# How to clean and find good url in command lines?

Tags: shell, url, url-rewriting, wget, ping

I have a list of URLs and I want to test them to get only the one witch work.

So I would like to do:

```
cat URLs.txt | testURLs > GoodURLs.txt
```

Do you know how to do that?
maybe ping or wget can be useful???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find "curl" to be usually better for this kind of checks than ping or wget. You could use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
while IFS= read -r line
do
    curl $line >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
    then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < $file
```

The execution changes a bit, but it's pretty similar to what you had in mind. Don't forget to make it executable with chmod.

```
chmod u+x testURLs
./testURLs URLs.txt > GoodURLs.txt
```